# Powershell system.io.compression zipping files and/or Folders

Tags: powershell, io, compression, system

Im producing some automated tasks at work where i need to zip certain files and/or folders.
What im trying to do is getting zip the text files  in folder 1 which contains 4 txt files.

Executing this command gives an error but still zips the txt files :

```
Exception calling "CreateFromDirectory" with "4" argument(s): "The directory name is invalid.
"
At line:15 char:13
+             [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source, "$Sour ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
```

What i got now is:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" )
$includeBaseDirectory = $false
$compressionLevel= [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal

$source = "C:\folder1\*"
Get-ChildItem $source -include *.txt  |
Foreach {
        $Source = $_.fullName
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory    ($Source, "$Source.zip",$compressionLevel, $includebasedirectory)
        }
```

Also if i want to zip the folders  inside folder1 i use -directory switch instead of include. 
that doesnt produce any error messages. 
any suggestions?

Comment: Your source directory name is invalid. It should be: "C:\folder1" (without wildcard)

Comment: Without the wildcard it will not list the txt files in the folder.

Comment: Use -filter instead of -include.  Include is for filtering the path.

Comment: That does exactly the same. Zips the files but produces an error for each file zipped

Comment: Edit:  It creates zip but doesnt zip the files

Comment: I would recommend using Add-Type over LoadWithPartialName e.g. `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@DavidBrabant is right that it is not normal to put the wildcard in the path, but I think you can get away with it in this instance as you are piping the results through a foreach statement.

I believe the problem is that your first parameter of [CreateFromDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485721%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be a directory name, but you have passed it a filename.  This isn't really helped by the use of variable names ($Source and $source).

When you call `CreateFromDirectory` it will contain the full name to the first zip file because of the following line:

```
$Source = $_.fullName
```

I'm guessing that as you have a filter '*.txt' you want to add individual files rather than the whole folder to a zip file then it is a little more involved.  See here for an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485720(v=vs.110).aspx

But if you simply want to zip the folder then use:

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\folder1"
$destinationZip = "c:\zipped.zip" 
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" )
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourceFolder, $destinationZip)
```

Comment: Only thing is that i want it zipped with its own original name. Also i only want some files zipped and no folders.

Comment: This one works :


    Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\test" -Directory <#norecurse#> |
    foreach {
     $Folder = $_.fullName
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($Folder, "$Folder.zip",$compressionLevel,$ExcludeBaseDirectory)

Comment: How do I increase the compression to make file smaller ?

Comment: @NigelFds -  Have a read of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485721(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.compressionlevel(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DavidMartin thanks thats exactly what I was looking for, cheers