# How to move a single txt file to the zip in powershell 3

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy/move one text file to the zip. I don't want to unzip it, copy the file and zip it back. Is there any way we can directly copy or move text file to the zip in powershell. When i am doing it in powershell, it's doing after that when i try to look inside the zip it's saying invalid path.

Powershell commands:

```
$A = "20160914.4"

New-Item "C:\test\VersionLabel.txt" -ItemType file

$A | Set-Content "C:\test\VersionLabel.txt"

Copy-Item "C:\test\VersionLabel.txt" "C:\test\Abc.zip"  -Force
```

> Error: The compressed folder is invalid

Comment: [How to create a zip archive with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12978117) you can do it manually via ZipArchive or ZipPackage or zip folder namespace. The linked question has many answers.

Answer (score 15):

**>= PowerShell 5.0**

Per @SonnyPuijk's answer above, use `Compress-Archive`.

```
clear-host
[string]$zipFN = 'c:\temp\myZipFile.zip'
[string]$fileToZip = 'c:\temp\myTestFile.dat'
Compress-Archive -Path $fileToZip -Update -DestinationPath $zipFN
```

**< PowerShell 5.0**

***To add a single file to an existing zip:***

```
clear-host
Add-Type -assembly 'System.IO.Compression'
Add-Type -assembly 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'

[string]$zipFN = 'c:\temp\myZipFile.zip'
[string]$fileToZip = 'c:\temp\myTestFile.dat'
[System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive]$ZipFile = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($zipFN, ([System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update))
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($ZipFile, $fileToZip, (Split-Path $fileToZip -Leaf))
$ZipFile.Dispose()
```

***To create a single file zip file from scratch:***

Same as above, only replace: `[System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update`

With: `[System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Create`

**Related Documentation:**

- `Compress-Archive`: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn841358.aspx
- `CreateEntryFromFile`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485720(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: NB: To create a zip file from a directory, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20070550/361842

Comment: ps. Some good notes on various zip pieces here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/381661/Creating-Zip-Files-Easily-in-NET-4-5

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Compress-Archive`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn841358.aspx) for this. `Copy-Item` doesn't support zip files.

If you don't have PowerShell v5 you can use either 7Zip command line or .Net

Comment: is there any other way to do this. i don't want to use 72ip

Comment: Only other method I know is using the dotnet library. Scripting guy already wrote a blog about this.  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/03/09/use-powershell-to-create-zip-archive-of-folder/